# How to insert ruby logic into style attribute in a div tag in erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm creating a Ruby on Rails application that takes certain input from a user and renders a report. I know how to insert ruby code into the erb file, but when I try to insert it into a style attribute in a div tag, it doesn't work.

I've already tried to do the calculations in the controller for infuencer_reports and then just inserted the instance variables into the show.html.erb file.

#### show.html.erb:

```
<div
            class="pie pie1"
            style="margin: auto;width: 100px;height: 100px;border-radius: 50%;background-origin: border-box;background-image: conic-gradient(
              #237e05 0 <%= @fitness_section %>deg,
              #0e89c2 0 <%= @food_section %>deg,
              #dd9b27 0 <%= @fashion_section %>deg,
              #8922c9 0 <%= @photography_section %>deg,
              #1ae6c7 0 <%= @kids_family_section %>deg,
              #f05d84 0 <%= @travel_section %>deg,
              #c94e22 0
              );"
          ></div>
```

#### influencer_reports_controller.rb

```
    @fitness_section = ((@report.total_category_likes('Fitness')/@report.total_likes)*360)
    @food_section = ((@fitness_section + @report.total_category_likes('Food')/@report.total_likes)*360)
    @fashion_section = ((@food_section + @report.total_category_likes('Fashion')/@report.total_likes)*360)
    @photography_section = ((@fashion_section + @report.total_category_likes('Photography')/@report.total_likes)*360)
    @kids_family_section = ((@photography_section + @report.total_category_likes('Kids/Family')/@report.total_likes)*360)
    @travel_section = ((@kids_family_section + @report.total_category_likes('Travel')/@report.total_likes)*360)
```

It should look like a pie chart with different colored section, but it comes out as one full circle of just the last color in the gradient.

Comment: I think you need to debug this. You can look at devtools and see what styles are there. Also, you can debug your variables

Comment: I did that, but I'm not sure if its because its a conic gradient, or if its because I'm trying to insert the ruby variables into the style attribute of a html tag.

Comment: Can you look at your resulted conic gradient?

Answer (score 0):

For each result, you should try to add a float on at least one of number like that:

```
((@report.total_category_likes('Fitness').to_f/@report.total_likes)*360)
```

And maybe add round method after

```
((@report.total_category_likes('Fitness').to_f/@report.total_likes)*360).round
```

eg.

```
360 * (100 / 124) => 0
360 * (100 / 124.to_f)  => 290.3225806451613
(360 * (100 / 124.to_f)).round => 290
```